# delete last row in table

Tags: javascript

I've got a simple question, I want to delete the last row in a table, I copied one function that deletes the checked one though:

```
function deleterow(tableID) {
    try {
         var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
         var rowCount = table.rows.length;

         for(var i=1; i<rowCount; i++) {
              var row = table.rows[i];
              var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
              if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                   table.deleteRow(row);
                   rowCount--;
                   i--;
              }
         }
    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

How do I change it, so that it will delete only the last row each time it's called? Thank you all for the help! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

the [deleteRow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/table.deleteRow) function takes an index, pass it `count - 1`.

http://jsfiddle.net/jbabey/HEDNZ/

```
function deleterow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;

    table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
}
```

Comment: yes! solved the case! thank you! 2 min. left, til submition )

Comment: This isn't covering your "is checked" case

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use:

```
function deleterow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    table.deleteRow(-1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function deleterow(tableID) {

    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
     var row = table.rows[rowCount - 1 ];

            table.deleteRow(row);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but I think something like this should work:

```
function deleterow(tableID) {
    try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var lastRow = table.rows[rowCount]; 
    table.deleteRow(lastRow);

    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: same story :) deletes the first row, not the last one

Comment: That's odd. Try this in that case:
function deleterow(tableID) {
    try {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var lastRow = table.rows[0]; 
    table.deleteRow(0);

    }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}

Comment: no )) maybe im doing smth wrong? as a remark: there are already 8 rows with header, in sum 9.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure if rowCount has some special meaning for you.

iterating with while-- lets you start from the back first.  Just break when you actually remove one.

```
function deleterow(tableID) {
    try {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var i = rowCount;

        while(i--) {
            var row = table.rows[i];
            var chkbox = row.cells[0].childNodes[0];
            if(null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                table.deleteRow(row);
                rowCount--;
                break;
            }
        }
     }catch(e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use 
table.deleteRow(i);

instead

table.deleteRow(row);
hope this works :)