# How to only delete last row of table?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this JS code to add and remove table rows when user clicks a button. Adding rows works like a dream. My issue is the user clicks the Delete button, all but the first row is deleted. I only want the last row to be deleted, say if they add to many rows.

**EDIT**
I have tryed this

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
if(table.rows.length <= 1) {               // limit the user from removing all the fields
    alert("Cannot Remove all the fields.");
    break;
}
table.deleteRow(table.rows.length -1); 
}
```

But when i take the loop out the Add button no longer works...

```
<script>

function addRow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
if(rowCount < 50){                            // limit the user from creating fields more than your limits
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
    var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;
    for(var i=0; i <colCount; i++) {
        var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
        newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
    }
}else{
     alert("Maximum Unit limit is 5");

}
}


function deleteRow(tableID) {
var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
var rowCount = table.rows.length;
for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
    var row = table.rows[i];
        if(rowCount <= 1) {               // limit the user from removing all the fields
            alert("Cannot Remove all the fields.");
            break;
        }
        table.deleteRow(i);
        rowCount--;
        i--;
    }
}

</script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10686888/delete-last-row-in-table

Comment: Then why are you running a loop to delete the last row.

Comment: For what ever reason if i do not run the loop to delete the last row. Im no longer able to add a row.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the last row of the table you can use this.

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
   var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
   var rowCount = table.rows.length;
   table.deleteRow(rowCount -1);
}
```

Comment: The problem with this is the user can delete all of the rows. I want to be sure that is not possible.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need a for loop, this code will work:

```
function deleteRow(tableID) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    if(table.rows.length <= 1) {               // limit the user from removing all the fields
        alert("Cannot Remove all the fields.");
        break;
    }
    table.deleteRow(table.rows.length -1); 
}
```

Comment: I tried this all ready. issue with this is. For some reason the add new row button no longer works than